# I played an online video in html5 player on google chrome, where is it stored on my local storage?

Tags: google-chrome, video

I pasted a remote video url in address bar of Google chrome and it started playing it in its html5 player. When video finished playing, i can replay it without any buffering which indicates that video is stored locally on my computer. I checked the cache folder for google chrome but did not find the video there, where does it go locally on my computer?

Answer (score 1):

#### where does it go locally on my computer?

There are several possibilities.

> Looking for your Google Chrome temporary files? It depends on your
>   operating system.
>
> Here is where you can find the location for a few common operating
>   systems:
>
> - Windows Vista: C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\
> - Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings[USERNAME]\Local
>     Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\
> - Windows 7/8:
>     C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>     Data\Default\Cache
> - Mac OS X:
>     /Users/[USERNAME]/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/

Source [Where Google Chrome Saves Temporary Internet Files & Folders](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/keN3Njx6gtM) by Sarah Dee

---

> There are also two additional folders used to store media:
>
> - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chromium\%PROFILE%\Media
>     Cache\
> - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\%PROFILE%\Media Cache\

Source [Google Chrome](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Google_Chrome)

---

> Nirsoft [VideoCacheView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/video_cache_view.html) will display information about all video files in the various caches it can find (including the download location).
>
> VideoCacheView automatically scans the cache of your Web browser (Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, Opera) and the temporary folder of your system, locates all video/audio files found in your computer, and displays them in one list.
>   You can easily choose the desired cached video streams and extract them into the folder you need.

If it has been downloaded into a cache you should be able to find it using this utility.

[image]

Source Nirsoft [VideoCacheView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/video_cache_view.html)

Comment: That's not really specific enough though. The cache itself is in `User Data\Default\Cache`, and I'm not sure if the video content is actually stored there.

Comment: I am using windows 8, I could not find the video file neither in cache folder nor in Media Cache.

Comment: It could be that the video is not cached at all or stored in pieces or not have a recognisable file name.